# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

Notification when keyboard shows or hides are called from animation block.
So when I register notification for selector keyboardWasShown: I want to change constraints inside that method, it is possible to do it without animating ?

Comment: yes it is possible by creating iboulet of the constraint.

Comment: i know how it works, but i want to do it WITHOUT animating.
There is no need to call UIView.animate... there, because whole notification is in animation block and i want to somehow change constraint without animating it.

Comment: without animating means????

Comment: it means that if i change constraint like this - 
self.exampleConstraint.constant = 30
view.layoutIfNeeded()

i want view to layout without animating subviews

Comment: What about `performWithoutAnimation`?